# Does PropertyValueFactory need valueProperty method in model or not?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am trying to make a table with a TableView and fill it based on a list of Actors object. The Actor Model is bellow.

```
public class Actor {

    private SimpleIntegerProperty actorId;
    private SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private SimpleStringProperty lastName;
    private SimpleStringProperty email;


    public Actor(int id, String first, String last, String e){
        actorId = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(first);
        lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(last);
        email = new SimpleStringProperty(e);
    }

    public void setActorId(int id){
        actorId.set(id);
    }
    public int getActorId(){
        return actorId.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String name){
        firstName.set(name);
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String last){
        lastName.set(last);
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String e){
        email.set(e);
    }


    public String getEmail(){
        return email.get();
    }

}
```

And here is my TableVeiw class

```
public class SakilaApp extends Application {

    private TableView<Actor> actorTable = new TableView<Actor>();

    private final ObservableList<Actor> actorData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Actor(1, "Mohsen","Parsa", "Mohseh.parsa313@gmail.com"),
            new Actor(2, "Morteza","Ghasemi", "Morteza.Ghasemi@gmail.com"),
            new Actor(3, "Mohammad","Fetrat", "Mohammad.Fetrat@gmail.com"),
            new Actor(4, "Nader","AhmadYar", "Nader.AhmadYar@gmail.com" )
            );

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));



        actorTable.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<Actor, Integer> idCol = new TableColumn<Actor, Integer>("Actor ID");
        idCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Actor, Integer>("actorId"));
        idCol.setPrefWidth(60);

        TableColumn<Actor, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Actor, String>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Actor, String>("firstName"));  
        firstNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);


        TableColumn<Actor, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Actor, String>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Actor, String>("lastName"));
        lastNameCol.setPrefWidth(100);

        TableColumn<Actor, String> emailCol = new TableColumn<Actor, String>("Email");
        emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Actor, String>("email"));
        emailCol.setPrefWidth(200);



        TableColumn<Actor, String> lastUpdateCol = new TableColumn<Actor, String>("Last Update");
        lastUpdateCol.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Actor, String>("lastUpdate"));
        lastUpdateCol.setPrefWidth(100);

        actorTable.getColumns().addAll(idCol, firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);
        actorTable.setItems(actorData);

        final VBox actorBox = new VBox();
        actorBox.setSpacing(5);
        actorBox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
        actorBox.getChildren().addAll(label, actorTable);

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(actorBox);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

My problem is that as they mentioned in this article
[How to use the PropertyValueFactory correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377820/how-to-use-the-propertyvaluefactory-correctly/16387259#16387259)

```
new PropertyValueFactory<Actor, Integer>("actorId")
```

will lookup for :

```
 Actor.actorIdProperty()
```

but as you can see in Actor model there is no any methods with the name of

```
IntegerProperty actorIdProperty()
```

My question is, Do we need such method or not?
if it is necessary, why this code works correctly?

Comment: As an aside, since you're using Java 8, then using a lambda expression is much better here anyway: `idCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().actorIdProperty());` if you have a property accessor method, and `idCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().getActorId()));` if not. Using this approach gives you compiler checks on whether the method exists and is of the right type, most importantly, and as a benefit it appears to be faster as it doesn't rely on reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "work" :-)

As long as the TableView is read-only, getters/setters are enough: data is shown as expected. As soon as the TableView is editable, the data won't be updated automatically. In the latter case, you'll have the option to either install a custom commit handler or expose the properties which will allow internal magic to work.

As you have them anyway, I see no reason not to (and *not* follow [buggy example](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38462) in the tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaDoc of PropertyValueFactory states that you need a field called

```
SimpleIntegerProperty actorIdProperty;
```

so really I think you should.

However, looking at the code of PropertyValueFactory I notice that it falls back to a getter if the property field isn't available:

```
if (propertyRef.hasProperty()) {
    return propertyRef.getProperty(rowData);
} else {
    T value = propertyRef.get(rowData);
    return new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<T>(value);
}
```

so that is why your code works as is.

If I were you I would follow the JavaDoc and rename your field to actorIdProperty because you never know when they could change the implementation.

Comment: The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) also says: "If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through support for attempting to call get<property>() or is<property>()", so it's safe to use with just the JavaBean-style methods. In Java 8, though, `PropertyValueFactory` is basically redundant; use a lambda expression instead.

Comment: I agree with @James_D. Using a lambda is much better than the PropertyValueFactory.

Comment: AFAIK, the field should be called `actorId`, but there should also be a method called `actorIdProperty`.