# Why is my table not being populated?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I know that there is data there because when I iterate through the list i can see that all my data is there. Even just printing my data seems fine but I just dont know why it just cant seem to make it show up

My method for populating database:

```
    protected void populateDatabase() throws SQLException {
        empInfoTable = new TableView<>();



        empIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("employeeID"));
        fNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("firstName"));
        lNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("lastName"));
        gNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("groupName"));
        hoursColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("estimatedHours"));
        payColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("estimatedPay"));



        List<EmployeeMaster> empList = getEmpFromDatabase();
        Iterator<EmployeeMaster> iterator = empList.iterator();
        System.out.print(iterator.next());

        empInfoTable.getItems().addAll(empList);
        //System.out.print(empInfoTable.getItems());

    }
```

Method for grabbing data from database

```
    private List<EmployeeMaster> getEmpFromDatabase() throws SQLException {
        List<EmployeeMaster> row = new ArrayList<EmployeeMaster>();
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AUStudentEmployees", "root",
                "password");

        Statement stmnt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from emp_info ORDER by EmployeeID");
            while(result.next()){

            String empID = result.getString("EmployeeID");
            String fName = result.getString("FirstName");
            String lName = result.getString("LastName");
            String gName = result.getString("GroupName");
            String hours = result.getString("EstimatedHours");
            String pay = result.getString("EstimatedPay");

            EmployeeMaster empInfo = new EmployeeMaster(empID, fName, lName, gName, hours, pay);
            row.add(empInfo);
            //empInfoTable.getItems().addAll(row);
            //System.out.print(row);
        }
        return row;
    }
```

Class with all string properties:

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class EmployeeMaster {

    public EmployeeMaster(){

    }

    private final StringProperty employeeID = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "EmployeeID");
    private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "FirstName");
    private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "LastName");
    private final StringProperty groupName = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "GroupName");
    private final StringProperty estimatedHours = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "EstimatedHours");
    private final StringProperty estimatedPay = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "EstimatedPay");

    public StringProperty employeeIDProperty(){
        return employeeID;
    }
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public StringProperty groupNameProperty(){
        return groupName;
    }
    public StringProperty estimatedHoursProperty(){
        return estimatedHours;
    }
    public StringProperty EstimatedPayProperty(){
        return estimatedPay;
    }

    public final String getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeIDProperty().get();
    }
    public final String getFirstName() {
        return firstNameProperty().get();
    }
    public final String getLastName() {
        return lastNameProperty().get();
    }
    public final String getGroupName() {
        return groupNameProperty().get();
    }
    public final String getEstimatedHours() {
        return estimatedHoursProperty().get();
    }
    public final String getEstimatedPay() {
        return EstimatedPayProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setEmployeeID(String EmployeeID){
        employeeIDProperty().set(EmployeeID);
    }
    public final void setFirstName(String fName){
        firstNameProperty().set(fName);
    }
    public final void setLastName(String lName){
        lastNameProperty().set(lName);
    }
    public final void setGroupName(String gName){
        groupNameProperty().set(gName);
    }
    public final void setEstimatedHours(String EstimatedHours){
        estimatedHoursProperty().set(EstimatedHours);
    }
    public final void setEstimatedPay(String EstimatedPay){
        EstimatedPayProperty().set(EstimatedPay);
    }

    public EmployeeMaster(String EmployeeID, String fName, String lName, String gName,
            String EstimatedHours, String EstimatedPay){

        setEmployeeID(EmployeeID);
        setFirstName(fName);
        setLastName(lName);
        setGroupName(gName);
        setEstimatedHours(EstimatedHours);
        setEstimatedPay(EstimatedPay);
    }

}
```

Edit: fxml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="650.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="studentempsignin.Admin_Controller">
   <children>
      <TableView layoutX="25.0" layoutY="29.0" onSort="#populateDatabase" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="empIDColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Employee ID" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="fNameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="First Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="lNameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Last Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="gNameColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Group" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="hoursColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Hours" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="payColumn" prefWidth="100.0" text="Pay" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: I tried it (I have added the `TableColumn`s also) and it works. Could you post the full code? How you create the table and how you populate the columns?

Comment: It really works?  I used scenebuilder to create the table.  And what do you mean by populating the columns? I dont think i did that.  Wouldnt the   empInfoTable.getItems().addAll(empList) populate the columns?

Comment: Yes. I have added the columns like `empInfoTable.getColumns().addAll(empIDColumn, fNameColumn, lNameColumn, gNameColumn, hoursColumn, payColumn);` right after the `setCellValueFactory` calls then everything works. This is what @Guenther proposes in his answer. But in your case as you have have injected the table from FXML, the problem is this line `empInfoTable = new TableView<>();`. Here you reinitialize the `TableView` (it was already initialized by the `FXMLLoader`) so you lost the columns added in the FXML file. Remove this line, and I guess it will work w/o any additional modification.

Comment: Add (at least) the `initialize()` method. Why are you populating the table in an `onSort` handler?

Answer (score 2):

Your `populateDatabase()` method creates a new `TableView` and populates it, instead of populating the one you defined in the FXML file.

Remove the line

```
empInfoTable = new TableView<>();
```

and inject the table into the controller in the same way you do with the columns, etc (note the `fx:id`):

```xml
  <TableView fx:id="empInfoTable" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="29.0" onSort="#populateDatabase" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="600.0">
```

and

```
@FXML
private TableView<EmployeeMaster> empInfoTable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your method populateDatabase() you are creating a new TableView object. You need to add the TableColumn objects to this newly created TableView object, e.g. like this

```
empInfoTable.getColumns().add(empIDColumn);
```

Similar for the other columns.

**EDIT 1**
In addition to that the name of the properties doesn't match the ones you have in EmployeeMaster.

```
new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("employeeID")
```

will look for a property named 'employeeIDProperty'. Please see https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html or here [How to use the PropertyValueFactory correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377820/how-to-use-the-propertyvaluefactory-correctly)

Comment: Still nothing.  Could it be something else?

Comment: if you are able to see the data being printed on the server side and cant see the output on  the view (jsp, html), can you show us that code?

Answer (score 0):

- Instead of using `List` or `ArrayList` make an `ObservableArrayList` and add the items to it so changes are reflected to the TableView immediately:

  ```
  ObservableList<EmployeeMaster> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList( );
  table.setItems(data);
  ```
- Note that the method `EstimatedPayProperty()` has to be `estimatedPayProperty()`.Also in the constructor use camelCase and play with (this.)
- Recommend to follow best practice by this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)
- Also you can have an improvement here for example:

  ```
  empIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EmployeeMaster, String>("employeeID"));
  ```

  to:

  ```
  empIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("employeeID"));
  ```

Comment: 1) `empInfoTable.getItems().addAll(empList);` adds all the elements to the `ObservableList` stored in the `itemsProperty`.
2) `EstimatedPayProperty()` is really named wrong, but the `PropertyValueFactory` will look for the appropiate getter method in case of missing property accessor method with name of `getEstimatedPay()` which one exists.

Comment: @DVarga Fixed the 1 :). About the estimatedPayProperty and getEstimatedPay() it makes a difference when you edit the table in real time.The first one reflects the changes immediatly at the table.Using get() the changes are not immediatly reflected.